# Hyperledger fabric composer delete card error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to deleting admin card using `composer card delete -n test@hlfv1` this command in my local environment. But I'm getting following error.

```
Missing required argument: card
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzTws.jpg)

Composer cli version is v0.19.0.

OS is Ubuntu

Any suggestions on this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The command you are using is not correct. Try this one

```
composer card delete --card test@hlfv1
```

For more `composer cli` command check [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/commands.html).

Answer (score 0):

There was a change in the command in v0.19.0 to bring more consistency to the CLI.  So `-n` was replaced with `-c`.

The changes were described in the [release notes](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases) for v0.19.0.